# How to mathematically determine the final state of a system after some Gaussian microwave pulse?

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics

I'm trying to figure out the final state of a system after some arbitrary microwave pulse (let's say some physical Gaussian pulse with a duration $d$, amp $a$ and width $\sigma$).

(I’m looking for how to do this for a one-qubit system)

This is what I've found so far. The Hamiltonian of a system can be described by
$$
H=H_0 + \sum_j c_j (t) H_j
$$
where $H_0$ is the time independent part of the Hamiltonian, which is
$$
H_0/\hbar = \omega a^{\dagger} a + \frac{\alpha}{2} a^{\dagger}a^{\dagger}aa
$$
where $\omega$ is the excitation frequency from the $|0⟩$ to $|1⟩$ state, $\alpha$ is the anharmonicity, and $a^{\dagger}, a$ are the raising and lowering operators. As far as I understand, the pulse will be within the summation term of the Hamiltonian somehow, but I'm not sure how to solve for the time-dependent coefficients nor for any of the $H_j$. Am I on the right track? How can I get the control Hamiltonian in terms of the amp ($a$), width ($\sigma$), and duration ($d$) of the Gaussian pulse?

Comment: What's the index of your `\sum` ?

Comment: @narip oops, it’s supposed to be j, edited for clarity!

Comment: Just to give some context, is the question about what are the equation is motion, or how to solve this analytically, or how to convert from a physical representation of the voltage, capacitance, etc. to a Hamiltonian?

Comment: @Lior I suppose I'm trying to solve for the Hamiltonian analytically, though I'm not exactly sure what form the Hamiltonian would take. Perhaps the amp, width, and duration correspond to a certain voltage and capacitance which could then be translated to a hamiltonian?

Comment: I’ll try to answer tomorrow, bit of a busy period…